# Random unordered_multimap using std::generate

Tags: c++, c++17, stl-algorithm, unordered-multimap

I'm trying to generate a random `unordered_multimap` of size 10 using the following code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    auto m = std::unordered_multimap<int, int>(10);
    std::generate(
        m.begin(),
        m.end(),
        [](){return std::pair{std::rand(),std::rand()};}
    );
}
```

But it won't compile with an error

```sh
 In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::generate(_FIter, _FIter, _Generator) [with _FIter = std::__detail::_Node_iterator<std::pair<const int, int>, false, false>; _Generator = main()::<lambda()>]’:
<span class="error_line" onclick="ide.gotoLine('main.cpp',11)">main.cpp:11:5</span>:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4438:11: error: use of deleted function ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(typename std::conditional, std::is_copy_assignable<_T2> > >::value, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::__nonesuch_no_braces&>::type) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = int; typename std::conditional, std::is_copy_assignable<_T2> > >::value, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::__nonesuch_no_braces&>::type = const std::pair&]’
  *__first = __gen();
  ~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/utility:70:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/unordered_map:38,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:378:7: note: declared here
       operator=(typename conditional<
       ^~~~~~~~
```

**Q**: Is it possible to generate a random `unordered_multimap` using `std::generate`? If not, what's the best way to do it?

PS: I know I should be using `std::default_random_engine` instead of `std::rand`, and I do in the real code, this is just for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: Probably not `std::default_random_engine`, but `std::mt19937` instead. Some implementations made [interesting choices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21843172/3002139) on that front...

Comment: Even if that compiled, `m` is still empty container, i.e. there is nothing between m.begin(), m.end(). `10` is bucket count in this case. Just use simple for loop and avoid all the trouble.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`std::insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/insert_iterator) class template to achieve what you're looking for:

```
auto m = std::unordered_multimap<int, int>{};

std::generate_n(std::insert_iterator(m, m.begin()),
     10, [](){ return std::pair{std::rand(),std::rand()}; });
```

Comment: `std::inserter` also compiles here. What's the difference between these two?

Comment: @PrzemysławCzechowski None, now that the template argument can be deduced. [It was convenient before that](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/inserter)

Comment: Ok, in `std::inserter` example, filling a set is done with:
`std::fill_n(std::inserter(s, s.end()), 5, 2);`. So should I use `begin` or `end` of the container?

Comment: Yes, it only saves typing. In pre-C++17, the class templates were the ones harder to type, as everyone would use the function template creating the type (e.g. `std::back_inserter` vs. `std::back_insert_iterator`). With class template argument deduction, this has changed. I would actually recommend using `std::inserter`.

Answer (score 5):

Your code can't work with a map.

From [documentation for `std::generate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate):

> The type `Ret` must be such that an object of type `ForwardIt` can be dereferenced and assigned a value of type `Ret`. ​

You can't assign a map item's key. The container "owns" the key. You can only assign the mapped value. [This method of "setting each element" is simply unavailable for associative containers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45167055/560648)

Furthermore, you constructed an `unordered_multimap` [with bucket size 10, but no actual elements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap/unordered_multimap), so your range is empty anyway (maps aren't vectors!).

You could do this with `std::inserter`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_multimap<int, int> m;
    std::generate_n(
        std::inserter(m, m.begin()),
        10,
        [](){ return std::pair{std::rand(), std::rand()}; }
    );
}
```

…but, honestly, just do this in a loop and move on. ;)

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
    std::unordered_multimap<int, int> m;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        m.emplace(std::rand(), std::rand());
}
```

Everybody can read this.

Comment: It's not hugely far from where OP was to `std::generate_n(std::inserter(m, m.begin()), 10, [](){return std::pair{std::rand(),std::rand()};});`

Comment: @Caleth You're right, but this is not readable or expressive code.